# How to make non-border arrow buttons with Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm using Java Swing to make a UI and the idea is to make it look like the native OS (in this case, Windows). I've used:

```java
setLookAndFeel(getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

And everything is good so far, except for one little detail. I'm trying to use the arrow buttons to hide/show a `JTextArea` like the ones described in [MS's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-progressive-disclosure-controls), the ones with no border as shown here:

[image]

I've tried using `BasicArrowButton` as shown below:

```java
BasicArrowButton arrowButton = new BasicArrowButton(EAST);
        arrowButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
            if (textArea.isVisible()) {
                textArea.setVisible(false);
                arrowButton.setDirection(EAST);
            } else {
                textArea.setVisible(true);
                arrowButton.setDirection(SOUTH);
            }
        });
```

But I only get the ones with borders, as shown here:

[image]

I've already tried playing around with borders and backgrounds but had no luck.

Is there a neat way to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: You can replace the button with ordinary JLabel and draw arrows from 2 ImageIcons, one per arrow state.

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4496934), it is known that the `BasicArrowButton` doesn't handle the border requests properly. So you might just have to build that kind of button yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [setBorderPainted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setBorderPainted(boolean)) method.

You don’t need to use BasicArrowButton;  you can use a regular JButton, and thus adhere to the current look-and-feel:

```
JButton leftButton = new JButton("\u25c2");
JButton rightButton = new JButton("\u25b8");
JButton upButton = new JButton("\u25b4");
JButton downButton = new JButton("\u25be");

leftButton.setBorderPainted(false);
rightButton.setBorderPainted(false);
upButton.setBorderPainted(false);
downButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

(Those characters are the “small arrow” characters from the [Geometric Shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes) block of the Unicode specification.)

You probably also want to hide the focus outline and enable rollover:

```
leftButton.setFocusPainted(false);
rightButton.setFocusPainted(false);
upButton.setFocusPainted(false);
downButton.setFocusPainted(false);

leftButton.setRolloverEnabled(true);
rightButton.setRolloverEnabled(true);
upButton.setRolloverEnabled(true);
downButton.setRolloverEnabled(true);
```

Alternatively, instead of calling `setRolloverEnabled`, you may want to add each button to a JToolBar, which will enable rollover, and in some look-and-feels, will leave the button transparent unless the mouse is rolled over it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I can't seem to make the focus painted stuff work as shown here: https://imgur.com/2JN6kfs. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? I tried both true and false for both properties but had the same result (yeah, you could say I'm poking blindly here, hehe).

Comment: @tete Does adding the button to its own JToolBar help?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be my idea since I'm trying to make a JProgressBar with a "details" JTextArea below that can be toggled (shown or hidden) when clicking on the JButton with the arrow. Similar to this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/win-dialog-box#progress-dialogs

Comment: Is that kind of layout incompatible with a JToolBar?  Indeed, you could add both the JButton and `new JLabel("More information")` to a single JToolBar.  You could even add [glue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Box.html#createGlue()) and a Stop button to it.

Comment: So, your solution seemed to be enough for the UX folks. So this will be the right answer. Thanks a lot.